# Using FrameLayout inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-framelayout

I have following `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/contact_selector"
    android:minHeight="64dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image_text"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/contact_circle"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="A.R" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image"
        tools:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/phone_type"
        tools:text="Ali Rezaei" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/contact_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="+989121895634" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        style="@style/LineStyle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you see there is a `Framelayout` called `id:image` in the layout. And the reason for it is using margins in `id:image_text`

```
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
```

Is there any solution in ConstraintLayout to avoid using FrameLayout in my case?

Comment: Did you want the elements in your layout stacked on top of the bottom elements?

Comment: Yes @IgorGanapolsky, that is right. you can take a look on it : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Contacts/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/contact_detail.xml

Comment: Could you possibly post a screenshot of what your layout looks like?  That code doesn't compile in other peoples' IDEs.

Comment: You can look at screenshot which has been used in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53783813/set-weight-for-a-view-inside-constraintlayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is exactly what you're looking. I've made some changes in the paddings (Added margins instead) and removed `FrameLayout`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="64dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_text"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_profile"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="A.R" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_text"
        tools:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/phone_type"
        tools:text="Ali Rezaei" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/contact_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        tools:text="+98912000000" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]